# Log of /_ah/start in App Engine instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a servlet mapped to url /_ah/start in my App Engine instance. It doesn't seem to be working and I can't find logging info from this servlet the way I can with all other requests. Since it is supposed to run as a separate thread, I can't test it manually in a custom request (because App Engine doesn't allow multi threading this way). How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What scaling type does the module/app use?

Comment: Actually not sure. Where can I see that info? It doesn't say anything about scaling in appengine-web.xml. I just have one application on App Engine. I use it as a backend for an iOS app. I'm trying to implement push notifications, and basically just use the sample code from this article: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/ios-push-notifications/

I just added the code to my existing project and deployed it, but can't get the servlet mapped to /_ah/start to work.

Comment: In that case it will be auto-scaling.  I'm not sure how/whether auto scaling uses `/_ah/start` but you can read [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) to find out more.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the solution would be to deploy the background thread code to a separate module. It will only be polling a task queue so I guess that should work.