# How can I disable logging of Google App Engine Health Checks: /_ah/vm_health

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

- I created a DotNet Core App
- Deployed it on the Google App Engine (Custom / Flex)
- I opened the logging tab

I noticed the following entry: `_ah/vm_health`
It is not there once or twice, it is there very large number of times

**Questions:**

1. How can I exclude this one from the logs, I know the system is checking if everything is healthy, and this is good, I just don’t want it logged.
2. How can I exclude anything from the logs? For example, there is an entry, and it is sending things to the logs, and wanted ignored by the log system.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841697/google-app-engine-health-checks-spamming-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable logging of the health checks: they're still requests hitting your app and they're logged like any other request.

In the [StackDriver Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) you *might* be able to use the [Advanced Logs Filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters) to filter out and prevent displaying of the undesired logs. I can't give an actual example, though, as I didn't yet use this facility. Just to be clear - this just prevents *displaying* the logs when the filter is applied, the logs are not `ignored by the logging system`.

Comment: But if I can't disable some items to be logged, or I can't control the auto delete of some logs, I will end-up with very large number of logged items that I do not want.

Comment: Not much you can do about that with regular logging. But if you use sinks for further log export/processing you could do some filtering there. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs.

Comment: Yes, sinks should do the trick, see here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607220/google-app-engine-disable-request-logging/72895859#72895859