# Deploying to Google App Engine does not work due to health check interval even though I am below the limit

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I recently made some changes to my app.yaml file (for a Node.js project) and decided to extend my health check pings to 4 minute intervals. According to the app.yaml [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks), the `check_interval_sec` should contain an integer t hat represents the number of seconds between a health check is conducted. This defaults to 5 but I wanted to change it so I did the following:

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
health_check:
    enable_health_check: True
    check_interval_sec: 240
    timeout_sec: 4
    unhealthy_threshold: 2
    healthy_threshold: 2
env_variables:
    NODE_ENV: development
# [END app_yaml]
```

As you can see, I set the limit to 240 seconds which is 4 minutes. When I deploy the application, it throws the following error:

```
[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"Invalid value for field 'resource.checkIntervalSec': '7200'. Must be less than or equal to 300\",\"reason\":\"invalid\"}]
```

Notice that the error says my `check_interval_sec` must be below 300 but apparently I submitted 7200? Not sure what's going on here. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Known problem, see [issue 36024384](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36024384).

The value configured in the `app.yaml` file is apparently multiplied by a value. More recently, including in your case, the multiplier appears to be 30.

So try to set it to 8 ;) And keep an eye on the issue (star it to get email updates) as when the fix will be deployed you'd probably want to update the configured value.

Comment: Aaaargh! I just wasted an hour trying to resolve this. I thought I'd made a stupid mistake of some sort. Thanks for letting me know. Hope it gets resolved soon.

Comment: Also check the linked post - the value you desire *might* not be the right one, you may need to do some tradeoff :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841697/google-app-engine-health-checks-spamming-app?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: any more news on this ?