# Why won't Google app engine observe my health check interval?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, health-monitoring, app-engine-flexible

I am using Google App Engine Flexible environment (Node.js)

I have my own custom healthcheck implementation, however it is getting run every single second rather than the 8 seconds I have configured below.

Since my healthcheck does some things that are non trivial I would like to remove some load from my server by increasing the interval

```
health_check:
  enable_health_check: True
  check_interval_sec: 8
  unhealthy_threshold: 10
  healthy_threshold: 2
  timeout_sec: 8
```

Any idea why my interval won't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploying to Google App Engine does not work due to health check interval even though I am below the limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886929/deploying-to-google-app-engine-does-not-work-due-to-health-check-interval-even-t)

Answer (score 0):

App Engine flexible health checks use the same underlying infrastructure as the cloud load balancer. From the [load balancer docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#multiple-probers):

> multiple probers simultaneously evaluate the instances... The interval
> and timeout settings that you configure for a health check are applied
> to each prober. For a given backend, software access logs and tcpdump
> show more frequent probes than your configured settings.