# Health API hammered on my GCP Flex application - how do I dial that back?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The GCP infra hits your app on '/_ah/health' to determine that it is still alive. My app is a 'Flex' type, and it is being hit **a lot** on that URL:

[image]

It is making the logs hard to navigate, apart from anything else :(

**How do I dial back the frequency of GCP testing the health end-point?**

Comment: Update your YAML file to include a customized health check option.

Putting health checks in app.yaml: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

Regarding logs: You can easily filter logs to not include any health checks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine health checks spamming app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841697/google-app-engine-health-checks-spamming-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [configure how App Engine performs health checks against your VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks) hosting your apps as part of the `health_check:` configuration in your `app.yaml`.

> ### [Health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks)
>
> Periodic health check requests are used to confirm that a VM instance
>   has been successfully deployed, and to check that a running instance
>   maintains a healthy status. Each health check must be answered within
>   a specified time interval. An instance is unhealthy when it fails to
>   respond to a specified number of consecutive health check requests. An
>   unhealthy instance will not receive any client requests, but health
>   checks will still be sent. If an unhealthy instance continues to fail
>   to respond to a predetermined number of consecutive health checks, it
>   will be restarted.
>
> Health check requests are enabled by default, with default threshold
>   values. You can customize VM health checking by adding an optional
>   health check section to your configuration file:
>
> ```
> health_check:
>   enable_health_check: True
>   check_interval_sec: 5
>   timeout_sec: 4
>   unhealthy_threshold: 2
>   healthy_threshold: 2
> ```
>
> You can use the following options with health checks:
>
> > **enable_health_check** - Enable/disable health checks. Health checks are enabled by default. To disable health checking, set to `False`.
> >     Default: `True`
> >
> > **check_interval_sec** - Time interval between checks. Default: `1 second`
> >
> > **timeout_sec** - Health check timeout interval. Default: `1 second`
> >
> > **unhealthy_threshold** - An instance is unhealthy after failing this number of consecutive checks. Default: `1 check`
> >
> > **healthy_threshold** - An unhealthy instance becomes healthy again after successfully responding to this number of consecutive checks.
> >     Default: `1 check`
> >
> > **restart_threshold** - When the number of failed consecutive health checks exceeds this threshold, the instance is restarted. Default:
> >     `300 checks`

By default the health checks are turned on and it is recommended not to turn off health checking just to ensure App Engine does not send requests to a VM which is not responding. Instead you can control the `check_interval_sec` to adjust how often you want your VM health checked.

You can always filter out information from the logs when viewing the logs. Check out the information on [Advanced Log filtering UI and syntax](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there's an [app.yaml config page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks)

As of date of posting, it doesn't say what the default is.

Here's what's **super weird** for the `check_interval_sec` var - My deployments are blocked by the GCP deployer, for certain settings values.

A setting of 200 for 'check_interval_sec', caused the deployment to fail with the following message:

```
"Invalid value for field 'resource.checkIntervalSec': '6000'. 
 Must be less than or equal to 300"
```

A setting of 20, caused the deployment to fail with the following message:

```
"Invalid value for field 'resource.checkIntervalSec': '600'. 
 Must be less than or equal to 300"
```

A setting of 10 worked, and it is indeed ten seconds in the console (though a bunch of threads his the JVM at the same moment for some reason).

TL;DR: seconds are not seconds in 'check_interval_sec' - at least for 'flex' apps.

Comment: That parameter field seems to be on drugs.  I found experimentally that a value of 60 just caused deployment to fail with message "ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] App Engine Flex failed to configure resources",  but a value of 5 was ok.  They could do better on the error reporting.