# Google App Engine updated health checks

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine Flexible environment (Node.js). Is there any reason why both the liveness and readiness checks are fired 6 times each at every interval second specified? (these are all at the same timestamp)

```
A  GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /readiness_check GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /readiness_check GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /readiness_check GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /readiness_check GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 3 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /readiness_check GET 200 2 B 3 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /readiness_check GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 200 2 B 2 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 
A  GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0 /liveness_check GET 200 2 B 1 ms GoogleHC/1.0
```

And is it normal for the readiness checks to continue indefinitely? I would have thought the readiness checks would stop after an instance was deemed "ready." Just doesn't seem necessary to have both readiness and liveness checks continuously hitting my instance when just the liveness checks would seemingly suffice. If anyone knows of a better way to configure this so that it isn't so redundant I would greatly appreciate it. The relevant pieces of my app.yaml can be seen below:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
readiness_check:
  path: '/readiness_check'
  check_interval_sec: 20
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
liveness_check:
  path: '/liveness_check'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 3
  success_threshold: 2
  initial_delay_sec: 300
```

Thanks!

Comment: some problems related to classic health checks, donno if the updated ones aren't affected as well: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42841697/google-app-engine-health-checks-spamming-app/43549496#43549496

Comment: Appreciate the response. I'd seen that answer and definitely think it's related, but was hoping there had been some improvements with the updates. I guess I was ultimately wondering if I had possibly been using the combination of the checks incorrectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of readiness checks to continue forever is so that you can, at your own will, remove a VM out of traffic rotation (e.g. you want to reload some cache, etc). Same happens with liveness. It also allows the load balancer to detect problems and remove VM out of rotation (if your app crashed and is restarting for instance) or heal it (if, say, the VM died altogether).

Regarding the number of requests - it depends on the number of instances you deployed (are you running 2 instances ?) and it works with 3 parallel requests per instance (from 3 different health checkers) so that we ensure availability and reliability of the results.

In the grand scheme of things, unless you are too aggressive and implement custom health check handlers that are too expensive, this should be minimal traffic for your VM.

Hope it helps,
Andre

Comment: Hey Andre, thanks so much for your response. So basically the liveness checks are meant to determine whether or not a VM should be restarted, and the readiness checks are meant to decide whether or not to remove the VM from the rotation altogether? I was only running 1 instance and still getting 6 parallel requests for each, but I did leave it as automatic scaling and set both the  min and max number of instances to 1 (which I could see causing an issue in that case). I can test multiple instances and log the instance IDs to check frequency with more than one.

Comment: I'm ultimately not worried about the extra requests per check. The major issue revolves around the fact that with the default settings for readiness check (5 sec intervals) and 6 parallel requests on 1 instance I was receiving 502 errors on a majority of my requests. When I increased the check interval sec to 20 the 502 errors disappeared. This was using 1 instance. When I increased my instance count I had to again increase the readiness check interval to 45 sec and the liveness check interval to 65 sec, however I still occasionally will receive a random 502 error from nginx.

Comment: Is there potentially something else at play that may cause the 502 errors at that level? The health checks continued to receive 200 OKs even when the requests start all returning 502s and there's no real indication in the logs what could be causing them. The number of 502 responses just seemed to be directly correlated with how frequent the health checks were being processed by nginx

Comment: We did find a bug in firewalls rules recently which i think is ultimately the reason for the behavior you were observing. It should have nothing to do with the timings you set. Could you try again now ? (with defaults should be just fine). Thank you!